# How can we write selenium ide commands in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, appium, selenium-ide

I hope, in my application an image is acting as a button. I tried to click that image with all the options but failed. Finally found from selenium ide, instead of click () cmd, I need to use clickAt() cmd.
Please, someone, help me in converting `clickAt()` cmd into selenium?
`element ID: "ext-component-4"` and with or without coordinates

Answer (score 0):

You can find out exactly which command in any of the supported languages corresponds to directly from Selenium IDE.
In Selenium IDE: Start by selecting you desired language from menu "Options -> Clipboard format". Then select the line(s) you are interested in and hit "ctrl+c" to copy the line. Open your favourite text editor and paste the command. It should then be converted to exactly what you want.

Comment: // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [clickAt | id=ext-component-4 | ]] ---- this is what i got!!! can you please let me know how to write in selenium web driver?

Comment: As it says - the command is unsupported in web driver. However, there seems to be ways around that, e.g. by using MouseDownAt and MouseUpAt instead.